# Meaning and usage of "big time"

Tags: meaning, phrases

> "Gabi agreed with rule changes big time."

- What does that mean? In which context is it appropriate to use and where it is not?
- Word order - is it always used at the end of sentence?
- Is it official english or colloquial  only? Is it US, UK or Austraila specific, or general English?

Comment: A [dictionary](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/big-time) answers much of this question.

Comment: Not the one I was looking up, @Andrew. And on the contrary, most of the answers you *won't* find in the dictionary.

Comment: What it means, where it goes, whether it is colloquial and whether it's general are all answered. The definition is given; the example shows it at the end of the sentence; it's noted as *informal*; it doesn't say it's used in a specific region.

Comment: Always show background effort. If you have looked up an online dictionary, include a link to the entry that you found, preferably along with the narration at that entry. Then -- only then -- ask what is left to be asked, what you found insufficient, unconvincing, or otherwise unsatisfactory. Who knows, you could help the dictionary publishers with your question if it so happens to be. Else the question may face closure -- I may myself vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used in this context as an adverb, it means 'to a great degree, on a large scale; extremely’. It is colloquial, and has its origin in the United States, and yes, it will usually be found at the end of a sentence.